# String/Int to double with precision defined onruntime

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an input type integer that represents a number that needs to be converted to double between 1-100, and the rest is decimal precision.

Example: 1562 -> 15.62 ; 198912 -> 19.8912

Right now, I tried a conversion to string, count the number of characters, take 2 to check how many decimals I have and depending of the result "create" a composite string to get a valid double...

Any idea of there is a better way of resolving convert-precision on runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
int value = 1562;
decimal d = value;
while (d > 100) {
    d /= 10;
}
```

Comment: I think decimal type would do more accurate conversion, since your code would fail with values like `1562123123`

Comment: +1 for a better answer with not involving conversion to string :)

Comment: @blacai: one thing I don't understand: how can you tell if 123 should become 1.23 or 12.3?

Comment: Well. For more explanation... the point of this is that I will have to parse initial double values (yes...they are double in the beginning, I will have to parse them to a string or integer, still thinking about it) and parse again to double to generate an output. This strange twice-conversion is because in the end depending on other external factors I don't know is the initial-first-time data I get is sent as a double or  string.
If I get something like 12,3 I will convert it to 1230 and in case 1,23 I will have 123.Yous also help me to do the first conversion applying a inverse with *100

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ `Skip` and `Take` like:

```
string str = "198912";
string newStr = string.Format("{0}.{1}", new string(str.Take(2).ToArray()), new string(str.Skip(2).ToArray()));
double d = double.Parse(newStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can add the checks for length on original string, and also use `double.TryParse` to see if you get  valid values.

If you have an `int` to begin with then you **can use `decimal`**, which would provide you more accurate conversion. Like:

```
int number = 1562123123;
decimal decimalNumber = number;
while (decimalNumber > 100)
{
    decimalNumber /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use string conversion and Linq to convert an integer to a double?

Comment: @PaoloTedesco, on reading the question second time, I see that the OP has an `int` to begin with. I thought the OP had string as the starting point.

Comment: I see :) I think I would convert to int and do some divisions in that case as well, anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mathematical solution.  The line `lg = Math.Max(lg, 0);` changes "2" to return "2.0" instead of "20.0" but I guess that depends on your needs for single digit numbers.

```
    static double ToDoubleBetween1And100(int num)
    {
        var lg = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(num)) - 1;

        lg = Math.Max(lg, 0);

        return ((double)num) / Math.Pow(10, lg);
    }
```